# Get Lead Id from Web-to-Lead, Update it based on Lead Id

Tags: update, web2lead, website-integration

I want to create web-to-lead form that i can update the another field in the next page form.

So the idea is like this,

1. User their information and submit it to our web-to-lead (Form 1) - (inserted in salesforce)
2. I get the submitted lead id
3. I redirect the Form 1 to Form 2
4. In Form 2, we set several Lead field so the new lead can update their data if they want (Like confirmation pages) - (i will update based on lead id)

Why we separated Form 1 and Form 2, because in Form 2 has many sensitive information. User might not want to give the information

What method i used if i want to achieved this things, API or anything ? can you give to me the resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can use web to lead Your Force.com Site to redirect user to other page.
You can create separate Visual force pages with Controller and redirect user to to second page for additional update.

Please visit following link it has detailed info.

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/creating-a-web-to-lead-form-for-your-force-com-site

Comment: can i attach force.com site to my own website ? Thanks for your response

Comment: You can use cutom domain in sites....you can Google for more information.

Comment: i try googling for web to lead from force.com site, but it said site can't update lead, only read and create. how do i solve this ?